# Have I calculated the Newtonmeter ($Nm$) of torque for my corded drill correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque

The corded drill is rated at:

450watts at 3000rpm

the calculation I have used is:

$$\frac{450}{3000} \times 2 \times \frac{3.14}{60}=0.0157 $$

I feel I have made a basic error somewhere (as the figure is very low) but dont immediately see it.

Comment: Use $${\rm Watt} = \frac{2\pi*{\rm rpm}}{60} \cdot {\rm N m} $$ or $$T({\rm N m}) = \frac{30 {\rm Watt}}{\pi {\rm rpm}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(kW)=\frac{\omega(rpm)\times T(Nm)}{60/2\pi \times 1000}$$

So it comes out to be $T=1.43Nm$ if I am not wrong.

Comment: You seem to have missed the 1000. But I don't know why it's not off by 1000.

Comment: probably used the actual value of $\pi$?

Comment: Probably. Also the power should be in Kilowatts.